# Update the status of SQL column on every Tuesday in php

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to update a column every Tuesday?
My approach is user can claim their rebate bonus every Tuesday, so when those who claimed their rebate bonus the status will be '1' for the week.
The status of **every** user IDs will be updated to '0' on the next Tuesday.

**Rebate table**

```
User ID | Status
----------------
a1234   |  0
b4455   |  1
```

On every Tuesday, the status for all User IDs in the rebate table will be 0.
Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Having to "automatically update a column" is usually a sign of bad design. Try to rethink your approach. For instance, could the rebate expire? In that case you can use an expiry date, without a need for automatic updates.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to run a job at midnight or thereabouts between Monday and Tuesday.  However, there are probably better ways to represent what you want, such as having "end dates" for the available bonuses.